# present perfect followed by present continuous

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Is the following paragraph okay?

> Syria turned into a battlefield in 2011. Since then, many Syrian people **have been driven** out of their country. A great majority of them **are flooding** into Europe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it.
It starts with simple past, sets a new time frame with *since then* and uses *have been driven* to establish the fact of the exodus, and describes the result with *are flooding*, a process that is continuing up to the present from the reservoir of displaced people.

Yes, Appolyon, your fused sentence works fine.

In fact, the *flooding* is subsequent to *have been driven*.

(I am answering the OP's question/comments here, because the software here suddenly won't let me make comments anywhere. It also no longer supplies a window to display the result of what I am typing in the composition window, and it asks me to complete a capcha to post or edit my answer. What a mess...)

Comment: Can the second and third sentences be fused into one? "Since then, many Syrian people have been driven out of their country, a great majority of them flooding into Europe."

Comment: Some people say the participial construction cannot be used to indicate a later event unless it is the result of an earlier action.

Comment: In this thread (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303561/and-fixed-himself-a-cup-of-coffee-fixing-himself-a-cup-of-coffee/303606#303606), people say "John got up at 7:30, fixing himself a cup of coffee" is wrong; making coffee was subsequent to John's getting up.

Comment: In that example, I don't see any reason not to use *fixed* - it's all in the past, and it sounds as if he was *fixing* while he got up. In your fused example, *have been driven* establishes a present condition that makes *flooding* from a reservoir of refugees possible. This may be a question of reasonable meaning, rather than grammar.

Comment: Something happened to my Firefox browser such that I had to switch to Chrome to make comments. Sorry about that.

Comment: But one could also argue that John's getting up establishes a condition that made his fixing a coffee possible. Still, the use of the present participle "fixing" seems weird.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what makes such rewriting into present participial constructions possible or impossible.